# How to subclass requests in python through inheritance

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, python-requests, specialization

I would like to specialize / subclass the requests package to add some method with custom functionality.

I tried to do this:

```
# concrete_requests.py
import requests

class concreteRequests(requests):
    def __init__(self):
        super(concreteRequests, self).__init__() 
        self.session()

    def login(self):
        payload = {'user': 'foo', 'pass': 'bar'}
        self.get('loginUrl', headers=header, data=payload)
        # more login stuff...

# my_class.py
class MyClass:
    def __init__():
        self.requests = concreteRequests()
        self.requests.login()
```

This way I could still benefit from `self.requests` members + my concrete implementation. So I could do: `self.requests.get(...)` or `print(self.requests.post(...).status_code)` and so on.

I guess that this line `super(concreteRequests, self).__init__()` can be stupidly useless since requests doesn't have any class declaration inside just imports...

So, the requests package can be subclassed/specialized through inheritance ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`requests` is a python module not a class. You can only subclass classes.

So basically you should just leverage its methods/functions inside your own
custom class.

```
import requests

class MyRequests:
    def __init__(self, username, passwd):
        self.username = username
        self.passwd = passwd

    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # do your thing
        resp = requests.get(...)
        # do more processing
```

What I wrote above is just an example to get you going.

Comment: Direct usage... Then, I think I'll do something like `self.session = requests.session()` in the `__init__()` then do methods like `self.login()` that call ie. `self.session.get()` and do more stuff...

- Thanks !

Comment: @JesúsFlores yes, exactly

Answer (score 6):

A good way is to subclass a `Session` object from requests.  A basic example:

```
from requests import Session

class MyClient(Session):
    """Specialized client that inherits the requests api."""
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_google(self):
        return self.get("http://google.com")
```

`MyClient` includes the Session (`request`) api for for free, and anything else you want to add to it.

A real-world example: suppose a client requires an auth header specified at runtime (in this case the auth requires a current timestamp). Here is an example client that subclasses `Session` and of subclassed `AuthBase` that achieves that (this code requires values set for api_key, secret_key, passphrase):

```
import json, hmac, hashlib, time, requests, base64
from requests.auth import AuthBase
from requests import Session

class MyClient(Session):
    """Client with specialized auth required by api."""
    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase, *args, **kwargs):
        # allow passing args to `Session.__init__`
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        
        # `self.auth` callable that creates timestamp when request is made
        self.auth = MyAuth(api_key, secret_key, passphrase)


class MyAuth(AuthBase):
    """Auth includes current timestamp when called.
       https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#custom-authentication    
    """

    def __init__(self, api_key, secret_key, passphrase):
        self.api_key = api_key
        self.secret_key = secret_key
        self.passphrase = passphrase

    def __call__(self, request):

        timestamp = str(time.time())
        message = timestamp + request.method + request.path_url + (request.body or "")
        message = message.encode("utf-8")
        hmac_key = base64.b64decode(self.secret_key)
        signature = hmac.new(hmac_key, message, hashlib.sha256)
        signature_b64 = base64.b64encode(signature.digest())
        request.headers.update(
            {
                "ACCESS-SIGN": signature_b64,
                "ACCESS-TIMESTAMP": timestamp,
                "ACCESS-KEY": self.api_key,
                "ACCESS-PASSPHRASE": self.passphrase,
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            }
        )
        return request
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to give you a complete example:

```
    # ----example.py----
    from locust import HttpUser, task, between
    import requests

    # Create fake api endpoint POST https://mocki.io/fake-json-api 
    class MyClient():
        def __init__(self, host):
            self.session = requests.session()
            self.host = host

        def create_user(self, *args, **kwargs):
            return self.session.post('{}/v1/9b021e1a'.format(self.host), json={"name":"something"})

    class QuickstartUser(HttpUser):
        wait_time = between(1, 2)

        @task
        def api(self):
            my_client = MyClient('https://api.mocki.io')
            my_client.session = self.client
            print(my_client.create_user().status_code)

    print('Executing client normally')
    client = MyClient('https://api.mocki.io')
    print(client.create_user().status_code)
```

You can execute the client code:

> python example.py

And you can execute the client with locust:

> locust --host https://api.mocki.io --users 5 --spawn-rate 1 --locustfile example.py

In both executions, you are using the same client.