# How can I use pythons request module with locust to load test bunch of apis

Tags: python-3.x, locust

I have an existing api testing framework which uses [requests](https://pypi.org/project/requests/) module of python3. I decided to use [locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/) module to load test my apis using the same framework. From what I understand [locust](https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/) uses its own client to make api calls.

Is there a way where I can use pythons requests module with locust? So that I don't have to write same code again for locust ( using its own client )

Please see that using requests module with locust does make the api calls but does not capture the response times  ( main thing when doing a load testing ) in both gui and non gui mode.

Answer (score 5):

I think you have misunderstood, Locust does not implement its own HTTP client.

Locust `User` classes just provide a wrapper around other clients and the most commonly used one (HttpUser) uses `requests`!

So if you call (for example) `self.client.request("GET", "someurl")` in your HttpUser subclass you will actually be calling `requests`.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#httpuser-class

Answer (score 0):

Locust is a wrapper. You can reuse your existing "requests" client in locust:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66270578/10299604